# Jquery Isotope conflict with fancybox gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, conflict, jquery-isotope

wonder if you can help me please...

I'm trying to create an image based site based around an isotope layout and then using fancybox to display galleries of images on click.

All seems to work ok apart from a rather nasty effect when clicking to scroll through the images in fancybox - see example http://www.andyingle.com/bugs/isotope/

Both work fine individually so I guess it's a conflict? Probably a z-index thing by the looks of it? I've tried other lightbox plugins (shadowbox) which work fine but fancybox is a little more elegant so would prefer to use that.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Many, many thanks!!

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Works in Safari and Chrome - what's not working? What's not looking as expected?

Comment: When the lightbox appears and you click next/prev the part of the image that is a click area goes black before the next image reappears. Have tested in Chrome and Safari and still struggling with the problem.

Comment: You should rather show a link to the page with the problem so we can debug it quicker and easier otherwise we will be just guessing

Comment: I did: http://www.andyingle.com/bugs/isotope/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's not a good idea to apply CSS rules to general elements/tags but use specificity instead. The "conflict" seems to be produced by your own CSS rules.

Yo have this CSS rule (line 131) inside your [hash](http://www.andyingle.com/bugs/isotope/css/hash.css) CSS file.... most likely you copied the styles from the original [Isotope plugin website](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

```
a:active,
a:active code {
  color: #1FB;
  background: black;
}
```

That rule makes the background of the fancybox `next/prev` selectors (which are `<a>` anchors) to become `black` when clicked (`a:active`)

You rather change that rule with some specificity like

```
a.thisAnchor:active,
a.thisAnchor:active code {
  color: #1FB;
  background: black;
}
```

or delete it if you don't need it